# InnoDB insert fails silently, works fine when table is MyISAM

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, innodb, myisam

I've got an InnoDB table in MySQL 5.0.77 that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `products_vendors` (
`vendor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`original_quantity` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`quantity` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`price` decimal(19,8) NOT NULL,
`created` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`valid_until` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`vendor_id`,`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm using PHP and PDO to perform an insert. When the code is executed, the insert fails silently. But, if I change the table from InnoDB to MyISAM, everything works fine. The InnoDB insert works if I run it through PHPMyAdmin.

I've boiled my problem down to this piece of code (my db credentials are correct as the MyISAM works fine):

```
$insert_sql = "insert into products_vendors (";
$insert_sql.= "`vendor_id`,";
$insert_sql.= "`product_id`,";
$insert_sql.= "`original_quantity`,";
$insert_sql.= "`quantity`,";
$insert_sql.= "`price`,";
$insert_sql.= "`created`,";
$insert_sql.= "`valid_until` ";
$insert_sql.= ") values (";
$insert_sql.= "'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7');";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$st = $db->prepare($insert_sql);
$st->execute();
```

What would account for this code working fine with MyISAM but failing silently for InnoDB?

Many thanks for any guidance.

Comment: What does your mysql log file say after the query on innodb?

Comment: Quoting integers makes them strings, which is useless since they will be converted back to integers to fit the columns' type.

Comment: The binary log records nothing when the insert is run against the InnoDB table. It records the insert when the table is MyISAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ideas :

- You forgot to COMMIT the transaction.
- Your persistent connection is in an undetermined state

Comment: Despite the fact that I didn't have an active transaction before, wrapping the command in a beginTransaction() and a commit() made it work. Also curious, I rewrote the code to use MySQLi and everything worked fine with InnoDB. Finally curious, this code worked fine on my old host but not my current one.

Comment: OK ! So some of your hosts / servers / DB adapters have autocommit configured to ON, others to OFF. I have no idea where that setting is, though. Usually, I issue a BEGIN at the first query which does data modifications, a COMMIT at the end of the operation, and have an auto-ROLLBACK in a register_shutdown_function in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I found the setting. It is an attribute set when opening the PDO connection. $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, true); When it is explicitly set I no longer need to fake the transaction and everything works as it should. Thanks for your help.